# PHP file upload doesn't work in customer server

Tags: php, upload

A simple upload script doesn't work in my client's server.
Records is normally transferred in phpmyadmin, but image upload doesn't work.

I think is a server problem because my upload script works great in my localhost server and in other domains, altervista, ecc.

I tried to check the PHP version (client 5.3.10, localhost 5.3.2) and the upload folder, It's ok.

I have to evaluate what could be the problem. How should I proceed?

Thank you.

Comment: check for the upload folder write permission present or not.

Comment: Please check folder's permission. It should be 777

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the permission of upload folders, permission should be 0777

Set it using the command below

```
chmod -R /path/to/your/upload/folder 0777
```

Comment: Comando: chmod -R /test/upload 0777 
Risposta: 500 CHMOD not understood

from filezilla command line

Answer (score 0):

It's because the permission of folder upload. you must set it write permission
the FTP Client support feature to change permission of directory on server